# I can't access hosted pages through IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I bought a new VPS, configured IIS manager in it, hosted applications as I've usually hosted on my previous servers. I can't access the hosted projects' aspx pages, but I can access projects' HTML pages. What is the matter?

These are the steps I have tried to host my application:

Copied all files to:
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProjectFolder`

[Adding application by Right click Default Web Site > Add Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0aXl.jpg)

[Provided root project link to application and set Windows User to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui36r.jpg)

[Checking project is published and running in browser, by Right Click Project > Browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPELy.jpg)

[Browser returning 404.3 - Not Found type error that is: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtWZi.jpg)

Browser returning 404.3 - Not Found type error, that is "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map."

Comment: Check your IIS installation - do you have turned on ASP.NET development features? [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/hosting-Asp-Net-website-on-iis/) you can find some hints on how to activate the needed features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Schneider says that you need to check you have installed the right .netfamwork in your server.

For exmaple, if your application is build with asp.net 4.6. You should make sure you have install the rigth version for asp.net.

You could check it by below steps"

Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off

Internet Information Services has subsection World Wide Web Services / Application Development Features

[image]

If you have installed that, I suggest you could run the following command in the command line to register the asp.net for IIS again.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

or

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```